# Discovering the iOS App Purchase Date

Tags: ios

I'm explicitly NOT referring to in-app purchases.

Is it possible to discover the purchase date of the application itself on iOS?

I'd like to reward early purchasers. Rewarding early users (those who launched the app) is **not** the way to go. I'd like to reward people who bought the game, for example, between Jan 1st and Jan 31st, even the portion of customers who who made the first launch on Feb 28th.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to update this, it IS possible.  Take a look at the answer to this question -- one of the fields in the receipt is "original purchase date".  There is also a video/presentation from WWDC13 that discusses this - "Using Receipts to Protect Your Digital Sales"

[A complete solution to LOCALLY validate an in-app receipts and bundle receipts on iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943183/a-complete-solution-to-locally-validate-an-in-app-receipts-and-bundle-receipts-o)

Comment: Also, even though the context of the linked-to solution is about in-app purchases, the original purchase date is in the receipt returned from the bundle method appStoreReceiptURL

Answer (score -1):

I am almost positive this is impossible by any method.

HOWEVER you could potentially store the date of their first "launch" of the application then do whatever you wanted with it.

```
if ([[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] containsObject:@"firstLaunch"]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"firstLaunch"];
}

NSDate *firstLaunch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"firstLaunch"];

if (firstLaunch < Cutoff) {
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: But users could essentially have purchased the app within the required date range, but never launched or installed the app on a device until after that date. Same if they re-install the app.

Comment: This is true but its the best method we can offer him. I assume his window would be wide enough, and the prize something not ultra valuable enough that it wouldn't cause any real issues

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately it is not possible.