# iOS In App Purchase security questions

Tags: ios, security, in-app-purchase

I have some questions regarding In App Purchase on iOS

1) Speaking of receipt validation: Is there a chance that the user was charged money but the receipt validation fails (for whatever reason) and then the user does not get his content? (In case, one needs the code to answer this question: I'm going to use [RMStore](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore) or less likely [MKStoreKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit))

2) Is it possible to store the App receipt (or the info of bought inApp products) securely in iCloud and then be able to download the content the user owns without him having to enter his password? Given that the user has various devices

3) How to store the info of bought inApp products on iCloud in a secure was, so that the user is not able to manipulate it? Is the "normal" key-value storing safe? Could the user somehow trick me into him having bought something in this case?

4) I heard that is is "bad" nowadays to store the pure productIdentifiers + Yes/No for persisting inApp purchases. I don't really see why this is a bad idea since it feels much more natural than dealing with these cryptographic receipts. What's the best practise for that?

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer : 
1| yes there is a chance it fails, it depends on your implementation, if it's local or remote (connection drops, ...) so it can fail in that case apple can reimburse that purchase (if i'm not mistaken). Also if you have user account you can implement a mechanism that allow you to remotely grant purchase to prevent reimbursement.

2| It's not a direct answer to the question, but to share purchases across device you should use the "restore purchase" mechanism. it's literally made for it.

3| I don't have the answer yet :)

4| it's bad to save the productIdentifiers + Yes/No (especially in userdefault) because this can be manipulated with apps like iexplorer on normal devices and if the user jailbreak the phone then it's even worse.