# In iOS 7, how to extract the values of Receipt Fields from the In-App Purchase receipts?

Tags: ios7, in-app-purchase, receipt

I know that in iOS 7, the app's receipt and the In-App Purchase receipts are combined into an encrypted format with a structure [shown here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html), automatically written to storage.

I know receipt(s) have fields, as [documented here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html).

I know how to retrieve the receipt combo by calling `appStoreReceiptURL`.

I know how to validate that receipt by passing it to Apple servers either directly or via my own server.

But how do I **parse the receipt to extract its fields?**

I need some kind of identifier for each of the possible In-App Purchases so as to record the user's ownership in a way that I can verify repeatedly later.

Answer (score 0):

If you send the receipt to Apple for validation, you will get back a JSON structure with all the receipt fields. Are you asking how to parse this JSON structure?

Comment: No, I am asking if I can later (after validation) read field values from the Receipt package stored by Apple in iOS 7. Apparently the answer is "No" unless I become a crypto expert and decode Apple's encrypted receipt. Instead, if I want the field values I should capture them at the time the validation response arrives from Apple servers. Correct?

Comment: Yes. Sending the receipt to Apple does not change the receipt on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Check the issue: [A complete solution to LOCALLY validate an in-app receipts and bundle receipts on iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943183/a-complete-solution-to-locally-validate-an-in-app-receipts-and-bundle-receipts-o)

In one of the provided answer author described the solution how to unseal PKCS7 container by means of OpenSSL and read all the contained fields. But using OpenSSL is only a one way how to read the receipt data. I also know another tool - [CargoBay](https://github.com/mattt/CargoBay) that operates with PKCS7 by means of native iOS methods without any 3-d party libs. I'd recommend also to check this question : [iOS Restore in App purchases with receipts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566425/ios-restore-in-app-purchases-with-receipts)