# Apple Receipt Device Hash Validation

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, rmstore

I'm trying to validate that the receipt is for this particular device using the code from a popular library for Receipt Validation called RMStore:

```
NSUUID * uuid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
uuid_t uuidBytes;
[uuid getUUIDBytes:uuidBytes];

NSMutableData * data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[data appendBytes:uuidBytes length:sizeof(uuidBytes)];
[data appendData:_parsedReceipt.opaqueValue];
[data appendData:_parsedReceipt.bundleIdentifierData];

NSMutableData * computedHash = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA1(data.bytes, data.length, computedHash.mutableBytes);

return [computedHash isEqualToData:_parsedReceipt.hash];
```

But the two hashes are not equal. Is there something wrong with the code?

**Edit**

```
    SKReceiptRefreshRequest * request = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] initWithReceiptProperties:@{SKReceiptPropertyIsRevoked: @YES}];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request start];
```

After I re-fetch the receipt once, the hashes start to match. This is the most bizarre behavior I have seen. Does anyone have an idea why this may happen?

Comment: Looks good in general, but I don't use RMStore for this. Could there be an issue with _parsedReceipt?

Comment: The above code is very similar to the code snippet in the first answer in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943183/a-complete-solution-to-locally-validate-an-in-app-receipts-and-bundle-receipts-o?rq=1

Comment: I take you're using RMStore as a basis. Does RMStore say that the hashes are different as well?

Comment: So I figured this weird behavior out: the first time, the hash does not validate. However, when I do fetch the receipt again using SKReceiptRefreshRequest (see edit in original post), the second time and so-on it starts validating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the answer from where you took that code, Apple recommends to refresh the receipt if validation fails. This is what `RMStore` does to validate a receipt/transaction:

```
RMAppReceipt *receipt = [RMAppReceipt bundleReceipt];
const BOOL verified = [self verifyTransaction:transaction inReceipt:receipt success:successBlock failure:nil]; // failureBlock is nil intentionally. See below.
if (verified) return;

// Apple recommends to refresh the receipt if validation fails on iOS
[[RMStore defaultStore] refreshReceiptOnSuccess:^{
    RMAppReceipt *receipt = [RMAppReceipt bundleReceipt];
    [self verifyTransaction:transaction inReceipt:receipt success:successBlock failure:failureBlock];
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    [self failWithBlock:failureBlock error:error];
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll just add one thing here - took me a while to figure out why my hash is mismatching...

receipt bundleId example:
ASN1 OCTET STRING (27 byte) 0C19636F6D2E706177656C6B6C61707563682E536B696E4578616D

Which is actually made of Identifier (0C), length (19) and value (63..6D).

**For comparing app.bundleId == receipt.bundleId -> use value only

For generating hash -> use the whole ASN1 buffer
 (otherwise SHA1 will result in different value)**