# In-App Purchases fail after rejected binary - worrisome?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Our IAPs were working fine in sandbox mode with test users. We submitted our binary for review but missed one feature, which caused the review team to reject it saying that the IAP feature could not be found in the binary (it was there, but more hidden than it should have been).

Now when I am testing the IAP functionality, I get `Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"`. I have read enough to assume this will just work again once we get the binary approved, but I'd rather not have an app go live with broken in-app purchases.

Has anyone had experience with this?

Notes: similar questions on stack overflow have been met with suggestions to delete the app from the device, create a new test user, and clear all provisioning profiles, all of which are not working. The products are being fetched correctly and the error is happening in `paymentQueue: updatedTransactions:` with the `transactionState` being `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed`

Thanks!

Comment: Are you testing in the Simulator?

Comment: You might want to check a detail explanation related to IAP that I posted here to see if you miss anything: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331456/ios-7-local-on-device-receipt-validation-and-in-app-purchases-check/23465611#23465611

Comment: @rob5408 no I'm testing on my device; it was working prior to the binary getting rejected.

Comment: @Ricky we're using the StoreKit classes without specifying a URL one way or another - is there a way to explicitly define which URL it is using? Or are you saying I should watch the network traffic to see which one it's using?

Comment: Have you checked iTC to make sure your IAPs haven't gone into some Rejected state under Manage In-App Purchases?

Comment: Yeah they're still all marked as "waiting for review". The note we got from Apple said something about editing them and saving because they were marked as rejected, but when we checked they were still "waiting for review". This whole process is pretty cryptic and Apple's error messaging doesn't help at all.