# Upgrade paid app to free app with in app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Im going to add a new version of my on app store. The earlier version was paid. The current app will be free with inApp purchase. I don’t want previous user upgrade to new version and they have to pay again for various products that were already present in previous version. Is there any way to check if the user had purchased the previous version of the app.

Comment: In iOS 7 receipt validation was introduced. Take a look at that and too see if the user previously bought your app or not. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have the list of those users in your database? 
If you have then set condition that, they won't need to update application(for those specific users only).

Comment: A list based on what?  Their Apple IDs?

Comment: Their apple ID and Device ID too. It would be more secure.

Comment: How does an app get the user's Apple ID?

Comment: I don't know what data they have stored in their database, so they have to select unique key only.

Comment: Can an app get the user's Apple ID?  Yes or no?

Answer (score 0):

I will also update my app from paid to free with in-app purchases and had the same thing in mind. I am using the [RMStore](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore) library to check the `originalAppVersion` of the App Store Receipt and unlock features of my app accordingly.

[This related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943183/a-complete-solution-to-locally-validate-an-in-app-receipts-and-bundle-receipts-o) and the [RMStore wiki](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore/wiki/Installation) provide the needed information.

Note that the receipt may not be stored on your device (at least while developing, I noticed), so you may need to refresh the receipt using `[RMStore defaultStore] refreshReceiptOnSuccess:^{} failure:^(NSError *error){}];`