# Validate and read iOS receipt on PHP server

Tags: php, ios, validation, receipt-validation

I've read a lot of discussions about iOS receipt validation, but I couldn't find a way to validate and read receipt content in PHP without calling Apple servers (that are very slow and cause my app to wait 4/5 seconds before opening).

Unfortunately my knowledge about certificates, SSL and encryption in general is poor so I need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943183/a-complete-solution-to-locally-validate-an-in-app-receipts-and-bundle-receipts-o) but in PHP and not in Objective-C/Swift. Can someone help me?

Comment: What are you going to achieve after reading the receipt ?

Comment: I want to check if it's a valid receipt and then analyze its content to see if there's an ongoing purchase (subscription). At the moment I do this by calling Apple servers and reading their response.

Comment: Why do you want to achieve this without calling Apple servers? Sounds hacking...

Comment: Because it takes seconds for their response and it's annoying. Apple provides a way to validate locally inside the app, I want to do the same but on my server, I don't think it's hacking...

Comment: I am the author of https://github.com/mbaasy/itunes_receipt_decoder. It's a ruby gem but it should help you to understand how to decode the two different types of receipts Apple offer. Feel free to contact me if you would like to collaborate in writing a PHP library.