# How to check Mac AppStore purchase confirmation in Delphi?

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

The software is written in Delphi/FireMonkey running on OS X. How to check if software purchased from the Mac App Store is not copied from other computer as there are no registration codes involved?

Comment: [About receipt validation (Apple)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html).  [Validating receipt from App Store purchase? (EDN)](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=229363&tstart=0)

Comment: See also QP : https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14234

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19943183/327083

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I'm looking for OS X solution, not iOS.

Comment: I think it's the same API?  See the local validation section... not implemented in FMX, in any case.